# Как обозначить права доступа

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем привет. У меня сайт с единой базой агентств недвижимости. Все объекты выводятся из панели управления сайтом. Как назначить привилегии, чтобы заходя в панель управления под своим логином, человек видел только свои объекты, которые он выложил ?

Comment: Добавьте в таблицу с объектами числовое поле, которое будет указывать на номер юзера создавшего запись данного объекта. Выдавайте юзеру объекты только с его id в данном поле.

Comment: Хорошо. Вопрос такой тогда, а как сделать чтобы именно номер юзера заносился в таблицу с полем где объекты?

Comment: Брать его из сайта и дописывать в запрос.

Comment: А можете пример привести ?

Comment: При регистрации пользователь вносится в БД и получает номер. В инфо таблице, как сказано выше, создайте доп. поле, указав тот самый номер юзера. Потом в выборке ставьте дополнительный `where`

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при добавлении объекта автоматический вносился и id админа в соответствующее поле, ибо в ручную прописывать каждый раз это не вариант.